# How can Firebase + Google OAuth be configured with a specific "hd" (hosted domain) parameter?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase with the Google authentication provider.

When using Google OAuth in other applications, I'm able configure authentication to be restricted to specific domains.

The Google OpenID Connect documentation details the "hd" parameter which is used for this functionality. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param

How can this be configured for Firebase?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Can't find nothing about that on Firebase docs.

Answer (score 4):

With the new setCustomParameters function, you can add the `hd` parameter

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('email');
provider.setCustomParameters({
    'hd': 'uw.edu'
});
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

Here is the API Doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider#setCustomParameters

Requires at least Firebase Version 3.5.0 - October 14, 2016.  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Comment: This is not working even thought the docs seem to indicate it is the correct answer.  Merp.