# Firebase | Retrieve hd parameter from Google oAuth

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-cloud-functions

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689734/how-can-firebase-google-oauth-be-configured-with-a-specific-hd-hosted-domai) on how to set the hd parameter. I simply want to check that parameter on a Firebase's `user().onCreate()` function. However, the hd parameter does not seem to be a part of the user object or token parameters. From what I understand Google oAuth should include the hd parameter if the user is from a gsuite domain. Has anyone successfully done this?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible. `hd` is meant to help select the best option from the list of users available to sign in as.